# Twitter page no longer exists, Token used error

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, share, twitpic

I am working on implementing sharing an image via Twitter in my application and I have come across this page.

When I run my app in my simulator I can no longer log into Twitter. I get a page stating that "This page is no longer valid. It looks like someone already used the token information you provided."

I have gone to Twitter and to the Applications page and removed this application to try again. I still get this warning page though.

When I try to run the app on my device it crashes when I tap the Twitter Button.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Or if someone could point me to a solid Twitter/TwitPic reference tutorial that actually works that would be great as well.

Comment: Looks like my app is mainly crashing during Authentication.  Anyone come across this any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these sample twitter apps source codes, will lead you for smooth implementation,

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

https://github.com/luciuskwok/HelTweetica

https://github.com/takuma104/ntlniph

http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/

http://jaanus.com/post/1451098350/an-example-iphone-twitter-app

Comment: Now I am getting this error:

[NSCFDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil value at objects[0] (key: oauth_token)

It looks like my oauth token key and secret are being found as well as my user id and name 

Don't know what the cause of this crash is though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem.

> Woah there!
>
> This page is no longer valid. It looks like someone already used the
>   token information you provided. Please return to the site that sent
>   you to this page and try again. It was probably an honest mistake.

Turns out the fix for this was simple although it took some hunting down!
The date/time on the server running the app had somehow become a day behind.
Twitter checks the time sync when using the API, and if the client doesn’t have the correct time, it’ll report the above error.

Comment: For some reason, I can't edit your post. Please, move your last sentence out of code so it would be easier to read and find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've got some loop or a method that is being called twice?